# UINavigationViewController embedded inside a UIViewController Container

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a nav controller as one of the child view controllers to my custom view controller container. There are two view controllers acting as children - the one on the left which is grey and the one on the right which is actually a navcontroller tree loaded from a storyboard which is orange.

Shown are images a. before navigation b. after navigation to the next screen and pressing back.

Why does the location of the button change by itself like that?

[image: Before navigation]

[image: After navigation]

Comment: are u setting up your buttons in code, or IB? Is auto-layout on? Is the nav controller set in code or did you embed it or did you add it by dragging?

Comment: I was doing it using code but changing over to IB has solved the problem. Im assuming the way I was setting it up was probably wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it using the container view control in IB has fixed the problem.